# calculate molecular weight based on chemical formula using python

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7.

For example my formula is `C6H12O6`. I used this code below

```
formula='C6H12O6'

s = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*)', formula)
```

and got this result:

```
s= [('C', '6'), ('H', '12'), ('O', '6')]
```

From here, I'm trying to figure out how to do this:

```
( C x 6 )+( H x 12 )+( O x 6 )
```

Can somebody help please, I've been stuck here for almost a day.
I also appreciate any other ideas.

Comment: do the letters represent some sort of numerical value?

Comment: yes the letters are elements.

Comment: so C is 12, H is 1, O is ,16  I have already made a dictionary for this

Comment: Try something like total = sum([w[elem[0]]*elem[1] for elem in s]) ? Where w is your dictionary of the atomic masses.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out !!

Comment: Note that a solution should handle the case where no number is given after the element name , like 'H2O'. None of the solutions does this at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I considered what you said above but It would be too hard for me at the moment, so I decided to put an option(type in 1)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of weights that map the character of the element to their respective atomic weights, and use the `sum()` function to do a summation of the list values you have.

```
weights = {'C': 12, 'H': 1, 'O': 16}
s = [('C', '6'), ('H', '12'), ('O', '6')]

total = sum((weights[e] * int(i)) for e, i in s) # 180
```

Comment: Ahh, much nicer way of doing it!

Comment: Thank you very easy to understand!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just get a more complete dictionary (the periodic table) for the entire elem_weight

```
import re

formula='CH12O6' #example molecule with singular element 

s = re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*)', formula)

elem_weight = {'C': 12, 'H': 1, 'O': 16}

total_weight = 0
for elem, count in s:

    #For singular elements
    if count=='':
        count = 1

    total_weight += int(count)*elem_weight[elem]

print total_weight
```